# Filtering string in column (counts of string) plus average of second column

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a way to filter a column "Role" for counts of string and get an average of 2nd col "Rank" for these values.
I tried value counts and string.contains but do not know how to bring this together.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Role':['Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward', 'Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward', 'Big, Guard, Big, Guard, Guard', 'Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big', 'Guard, Big, Guard, Guard, Big','Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big' ],
        'Rank':[10, 6, 5, 2, 1, 3]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

df

```
   Role                               Rank
0  Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward    10
1  Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward     6
2    Big, Guard, Big, Guard, Guard     5
3    Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big     2
4    Guard, Big, Guard, Guard, Big     1
5    Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big     3
```

Idea of result filtering for "2* Big", .........

```
Role                   Value count    Rank/avg 
Big, Big               4               5.5 
Big, Big, Big          2               2.5
```

Just edited the values for two Bigs, original df is two big to add  here. Output of 2*Big and 3* Big is result wished for.

Comment: Can you give the full expected output matching the provided input?

Comment: How come Big*2 only has a count of 2? It matches rows 0,1,2,4

Comment: just corrected the manual mistake

Comment: Added second Big scenario looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same output format, but if what you are looking for is the `Rank/avg`, maybe that helps you:

```py
data = {'Role':['Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward', 'Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward', 'Big, Guard, Big, Guard, Guard', 'Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big', 'Guard, Big, Guard, Guard, Big','Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big' ],
        'Rank':[10, 6, 5, 2, 1, 3]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Role'] = df['Role'].str.strip()
# Create another column to hold `Role` values as a list
df['Role2'] = df['Role'].str.split(', ')
# Count how many times each role appears in each `Role` value
role_counts = df['Role2'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).value_counts())
# Merge with original dataframe
df2 = df.merge(role_counts, left_index=True, right_index=True)
# Calculate average by `Role` count
df2[role_counts.columns] = df2[role_counts.columns].fillna(0)
df2['Rank avg'] = 0
for col in role_counts:
    df2['Rank avg'] = df2.groupby(col)['Rank'].transform('mean')

print(df2)
```

Output:

| - | Role | Rank | Role2 | Big | Guard | Forward | Rank avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward | 10 | [Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward] | 2.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 5.25 |
| 1 | Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward | 6 | [Big, Big, Guard, Guard, Forward] | 2.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 5.25 |
| 2 | Big, Guard, Big, Guard, Guard | 5 | [Big, Guard, Big, Guard, Guard] | 2.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 3.00 |
| 3 | Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big | 2 | [Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big] | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 5.25 |
| 4 | Guard, Big, Guard, Guard, Big | 1 | [Guard, Big, Guard, Guard, Big] | 2.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 3.00 |
| 5 | Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big | 3 | [Big, Big, Guard, Forward, Big] | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 5.25 |

Comment: Any idea how I can change that it counts: how often three "Bigs"  indepent  on the other terms appear?  Meaning row 5 and row 3 would be counted together and the rank of these rows would be handled same way.

Comment: Using the output dataframe, you can count the rows: `df2[df2['Big']==3].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can first `split` and `explode` the strings, then perform a double `groupby.agg`:

```
(df
 .assign(Role=df['Role'].str.split(', '))
 .explode('Role')
 .reset_index()
 .groupby(['index', 'Role'], as_index=False)
 .agg({'Role': ','.join, 'Rank': 'first'})
 .groupby('Role')
 .agg(**{'Value count': ('Role', 'count'),
         'Rank_avg': ('Rank', lambda x: x.sum()/len(x))
        })
)
```

output:

```
                   Value count  Rank_avg
Role                                    
Big,Big                      4      5.50
Big,Big,Big                  2      2.50
Forward                      4      5.25
Guard                        2      2.50
Guard,Guard                  2      8.00
Guard,Guard,Guard            2      3.00
```